# Exclude project from a dependency in Gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, dependencies

I'd like to exclude some unused dependencies to reduce my app size. Here are the dependencies in my module:

```
    +--- project :ProjectOne
|    +--- commons-io:commons-io:2.4
|    \--- project :ProjectTwo
|         +--- com.project:PackJPG:1.5
|         +--- com.project:xz:1.2
|         +--- org.ocpsoft.prettytime:prettytime:2.1.2.Final
|         +--- joda-time:joda-time:2.1
|         +--- project :ProjectThree
|         |    +--- project :Utilities
|         |    +--- project :ProcessPriority
|         |    |    +--- com.nativelibs4java:bridj:0.6.2
|         |    |    |    \--- com.google.android.tools:dx:1.7
|         |    |    +--- net.java.dev.jna:jna:4.1.0
|         |    |    +--- net.java.dev.jna:jna-platform:4.1.0
|         |    |    |    \--- net.java.dev.jna:jna:4.1.0
|         |    |    +--- org.tinylog:slf4j-binding:1.2
|         |    |    |    +--- org.tinylog:tinylog:1.2
|         |    |    |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:[1.6,1.8) -> 1.7.25
|         |    |    \--- project :Utilities
|         |    +--- project :ProjectFour
|         |    |    +--- commons-logging:commons-logging:1.2
|         |    |    +--- org.tinylog:jcl-binding:1.2
|         |    |    |    +--- org.tinylog:tinylog:1.2
|         |    |    |    \--- commons-logging:commons-logging:[1.2,1.3) -> 1.2
|         |    |    \--- commons-codec:commons-codec:1.10
|         |    +--- org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:1.7.25
|         |    |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25
|         |    +--- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:1.7.25
|         |    |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25
|         |    +--- com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:2.6.1
|         |    +--- com.google.inject:guice:4.1.0
|         |    |    +--- javax.inject:javax.inject:1
|         |    |    \--- com.google.guava:guava:19.0
|         |    +--- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk16:1.46
|         |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:19.0
|         |    +--- com.drewnoakes:metadata-extractor:2.9.1
|         |    |    \--- com.adobe.xmp:xmpcore:5.1.2
|         |    +--- com.mixpanel:mixpanel-java:1.4.4
|         |    |    \--- org.json:json:20090211
|         |    \--- com.mortennobel:java-image-scaling:0.8.6
|         |         \--- com.jhlabs:filters:2.0.235
|         +--- project :PackJPGInterFileCompression
|         |    +--- project :ProjectFive (*)
|         |    \--- com.project:PackJPG:1.5
|         +--- com.h2database:h2:1.3.176
|         +--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7
|         +--- org.json:json:20080701 -> 20090211
|         \--- itadaki:jbzip2:0.9.1
```

And my gradle file:

```
implementation (project(':ProjectOne')) {
        exclude group: 'ProjectTwo'
}
```

Even when I exclude ProjectTwo from ProjectOne, I still find it in the dependency tree on Line 3 somehow. What am I missing?

Comment: have you checked "settings.gradle" file for dependency of project

Comment: @ParthBhatti I have done that. It includes all the modules in the project. I did get my solution from Paresh Mayani but you could give your solution, as well. How's settings.Gradle useful in this matter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are actually excluding group where as I believe you want to exclude complete ProjectTwo module.

If I am not wrong then try:

```
configurations {
    compile.exclude module: 'ProjectTwo'
}
```